# dependent create and access a has_many by type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have some models that essentially look like:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
  belongs_to :child_type 
end

class ChildType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children
end
```

There are 3 entries of ChildType and when I create a new Parent object, I'd like to go ahead and create the dependent Child objects, one for each child type.

Is there a cleaner way of doing this rather than:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children

  after_create :create_children

  private

  def create_children
    ChildType.all.each do |ct|
      children.create(child_type_id: ct.id)
    end
  end
end
```

This works but I'm wondering if rails has a cleaner way of doing this.

Secondly I'd also like shortcut methods on the parent so I can easily access the three children by type:

```
Parent.find(id).child_type_1 # returns children.where(child_type: { id: 1 }).first
```

I could create a scope on Child that takes an argument for type but if possible I'd rather have a method on the parent to load it, if there's a clean way of doing that. I can make 3 methods on the parent to find the appropriate child of each type but that's not super DRY...

Answer (score 0):

you can use [accepts_nested_attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) instead of callback (you should change after_create -> after_save because of deprecation for new rails ver)

If you want access children list base on child_type:

```
@child_type = ChildType.find(params[:child_tye_id])
@child_list = @child_type.children
```

It should use by association which you defined